# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings' while running python in iOS

Tags: python, ios, python-3.x, swift, xcode

I am trying to integrate python in iOS. I tried same thing as mentioned here - https://github.com/beeware/Python-Apple-support/tree/3.9

Here is my python script in Xcode projects

```
func RunPythonScript() -> PythonObject {
    
    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource:"/Users/projects/extra/python_apple_support/PAS_10_11_v3/PAS_10_11_v3/Resources/",
                    ofType: nil) {
        setenv("PYTHONPATH", path, 1)
        setenv("PYTHONHOME", path, 1)

      }
    
    let sys = Python.import("sys")
    sys.path.append("/Users/projects/extra/python_apple_support/PAS_10_11_v3/PAS_10_11_v3/PAS_10_11_v3/")
    let file = Python.import("pythonscript")
    
    let response = file.hello_world()
    print(response)
    return response
}
```

It builds successfully but when I call python program it end up saying

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = (not set)
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = 'python3'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = '/Users/karimkhan/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C444D135-C393-4631-AFE2-FF5F86935EF6/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/642E9540-CBAF-448C-8E8D-856B8E5D03EC/PAS_10_11_v3.app/PAS_10_11_v3'
  sys.base_prefix = '/Users/runner/work/Python-Apple-support/Python-Apple-support/install/iOS/iphonesimulator.x86_64/python-3.9.14'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = '/Users/runner/work/Python-Apple-support/Python-Apple-support/install/iOS/iphonesimulator.x86_64/python-3.9.14'
  sys.platlibdir = 'lib'
  sys.executable = '/Users/karimkhan/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C444D135-C393-4631-AFE2-FF5F86935EF6/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/642E9540-CBAF-448C-8E8D-856B8E5D03EC/PAS_10_11_v3.app/PAS_10_11_v3'
  sys.prefix = '/Users/runner/work/Python-Apple-support/Python-Apple-support/install/iOS/iphonesimulator.x86_64/python-3.9.14'
  sys.exec_prefix = '/Users/runner/work/Python-Apple-support/Python-Apple-support/install/iOS/iphonesimulator.x86_64/python-3.9.14'
  sys.path = [
    '/Users/runner/work/Python-Apple-support/Python-Apple-support/install/iOS/iphonesimulator.x86_64/python-3.9.14/lib/python39.zip',
    '/Users/runner/work/Python-Apple-support/Python-Apple-support/install/iOS/iphonesimulator.x86_64/python-3.9.14/lib/python3.9',
    '/Users/runner/work/Python-Apple-support/Python-Apple-support/install/iOS/iphonesimulator.x86_64/python-3.9.14/lib/lib-dynload',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x0000000108fd4600 (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>
```

Answer (score 3):

I just got this working after days of trying! Using Python 3.11.

For anyone wondering, we're using a version of Python patched for iOS (from Beeware's [Python Apple Support](https://github.com/beeware/Python-Apple-support)), and [PythonKit](https://github.com/pvieito/PythonKit) (Swift pkg) to embed Python in an iOS app using Xcode. The goal (for me at least) is to do my UI in SwiftUI, but use my own Python logic on some of the app's data.

OP, I don't know what all of your problems might be (there could be several), but I am immediately noticing at least one thing wrong. You're looking **on your mac** for Python when your goal is to put Python itself inside of your app. **You should be looking in the app** for the directory containing the Python standard library ('python-stdlib'), *as well as* the 'lib-dynload' subdir, provided to you by Beeware's Python Apple Support repo. You want to set PYTHONPATH and PYTHONHOME to this combo of paths.

This post is intended to supplement to "How to embed a Python interpreter in an iOS app - presented by Łukasz Langa." on YT.

In the video the OP linked to, Lukasz's 'python-stdlib' has a different name and a very different directory structure than the latest version of Py for iOS provides. What you'll need to figure out is the path to the 'python-stdlib' dir, AND [probably] its subdir, 'lib-dynload'. *Counterintuitively, you do need to specify both, even though the latter is a subdir of the former.*

Your line:

```
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource:"/Users/projects/extra/python_apple_support/PAS_10_11_v3/PAS_10_11_v3/Resources/",
                    ofType: nil) {
```

Should read something like:

```
if let libPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "python-stdlib", ofType: nil),
   let libPath2 = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "python-stdlib/lib-dynload", ofType: nil) {
        
    let mergedPaths = "\(libPath):\(libPath2)"
```

...where 'python-stdlib' is the PATH of the python libraries directory--not just the directory name. (If that's confusing to a newbie, this is the same: `let mergedPaths = libPath + ":" + libPath2`.

To get an idea of the path, go to Product > Show Build Folder in Finder, then find Products/Debug-iphonesimulator, right click .app (the greyed / X'd out icon) > Show package contents.

Assuming you have properly copied this stuff into the project, you should be able to find 'python-stdlib' inside the .app. For me, it was right in the root of the .app (since that's where I effectively put it, by adding it to the GROUP (not dir!) called 'Resources'. (Because Resources is a group, whatever is in there will be in the root level of the .app, NOT in a dir called Resources. It seems [there can be groups that *are* backed by folders, and groups that *are not*.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/managing-files-and-folders-in-your-xcode-project) This is an important distinction.)

Now, set PYTHONPATH and PYTHONHOME to `mergedPaths` like you were doing:

```
setenv("PYTHONHOME", mergedPaths, 1)    
setenv("PYTHONPATH", mergedPaths, 1)
```

If you don't include the path to 'lib-dynload', then this will **only** work in the simulator. Why would it work at all? Lovely question...

**IMPORTANT:** The script.py file Lukasz created for his custom Python code must go into the 'python-stdlib' directory for this to work. I imagine you could stick it anywhere, as long as you append its new path to `mergedPaths`, as can be seen in a project generated by Beeware's Briefcase. To append that path to the merged paths, you're just concatenating strings with a ":" between each path. I have not tested this.

**COPYING THE LIBRARY PROPERLY**

Here's something that screwed me up for a while:
When you *copy* over Python.xcframework and the std-lib, make sure you're creating *folders* and not *groups* (in the prompt after you drag and drop), else you will end up with hundreds of errors due to the flattening of directories resulting from creating groups and not dirs (think of every **main**.py from the lib ending up in the same folder--no bueno). Make sure your prompt looks exactly like this:

[screenshot of said prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCegm.png) ☝

**SIGNING THE PYTHON LIBRARY**

Follow 'The Manual Way' > Step 6 @ [Python Apple Support > USAGE.md](https://github.com/beeware/Python-Apple-support/blob/main/USAGE.md).

All I had to change was this line segment:

```
"$CODESIGNING_FOLDER_PATH/Contents/Resources/python-stdlib/lib-dynload"
```

Due to *my* directory structure ('python-stdlib' in root of .app), I changed it to:

```
"$CODESIGNING_FOLDER_PATH/python-stdlib/lib-dynload"
```

...omitting the extra directories in the path to 'lib-dynload'.

**ALMOST FORGOT--module.modulemap!**

Assuming you have created 'module.modulemap', and copied it to all three locations (in the Xcode project and in both Headers dirs in the framework), you'll want it to read like this:

```
module Python {
    umbrella header "Python.h"
    export *
    link "python-stdlib"
}
```

...where Lukasz's read `link Python`, ours must read `link python-stdlib`, as above. I wouldn't be surprised this is actually the *path* to 'python-stdlib'. Again, mine is right in the root of the .app, so under that assumption, the name is also the path, here. I have not tested this theory.

**NOT NECESSARILY RELEVANT TO THE SOLUTION BUT MAYBE ENTERTAINING**

This part is pretty amazing. I've had this working in the simulator only for the last several days. For most of that time, on the device, it would import Random, but not Math (which was being called from Random). Then I figured how to point the app to both 'python-stdlib' and 'python-stdlib/lib-dynload'. Got a new error -- code signature invalid for '.../math.cpython-311-iphoneos.so' (that Python math module!) in 'lib-dynload'! Wow! It was finally SEEING the math module.

PARTIAL CONSOLE OUTPUT:

```
...(code signature in <45B34416-425D-3E01-BC39-CB7A8C170A0A> '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/1465B572-3399-4B76-B017-4EE168637AF5/SIXTH_try.app/python-stdlib/lib-dynload/math.cpython-311-iphoneos.so' not valid for use in process: mapped file has no cdhash, completely unsigned? Code has to be at least ad-hoc signed.)
```

Here's the amazing part... YESTERDAY, I told Github to tell me about any changes to Beeware's Python Apple Support. Last night at 7pm, I get a notification that dude updated the USAGE.md *to add instructions for code signing*! Ha! What are the chances that this would happen on exactly the day that I need it to happen. Anyway, I followed [those instructions](https://github.com/beeware/Python-Apple-support/blob/main/USAGE.md), ran on my phone, and WHUHBAM! MY IPHONE IS USING THE RANDOM MODULE TO GENERATE INTS UPON A BUTTON TAP! THE WHOLE GUI WAS MADE IN SWIFTUI. HOLY MOTHER#(@)!@$ IT'S WORKING! (I realize enthusiasm and emotion are not always welcome on SO, but I'm going to celebrate, and no one will stop me!)

Comment: Thanks man, finally got Python running on my phone.  I didn't have to change the `link "Python"` line in the module map though, that worked fine with the original version as described by Lukasz.